# Edit appears to be from post owner but may not be. Attempt to hijack question?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing suggested edits I came across this one.

https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/389330

At first glance it looks like an edit from the original poster, but the user numbers don't match so I'm not sure what should be done in a situation such as this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user details which you cannot see do appear to match up, despite different emails (hence different avatars). I would put money on them being the same person.

That said, you couldn't see this.
Rejecting was a perfectly good reaction.

In future, use similar logic and flag or Meta it up for consensus.